# How can I set data in a state in FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to **save product ID** (`item.id`) in a state like `productId`.

I need to product Id for add product to cart.

When I click on `TouchableOpacity` working fine but `productId` always is 4.

I have three Item. The `id` of last item is 4 and first item is 2.

When I click on `TouchableOpacity` of product 1, id is 4 but should be 2.

I see IDs are OK When I print IDs in listView.

```
  <FlatList
     data={this.state.dataSource}
     renderItem={({item}) =>

     <View>
     <View>

     <Text>{item.title} - {item.type}</Text>
     <Text>{item.id}</Text>

     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.decrementCount,()=>this.setState({productId:item.id})}>

     <AntDesign name="minus" size={15} style={{color:'#fff'}}/>

     </TouchableOpacity>


     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.incrementCount} activeOpacity={0.5}>
     <AntDesign name="plus" size={15} style={{color:'#fff'}}/>

     </TouchableOpacity>

     </View>
     </View>

     }
     />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line is your issue:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.decrementCount,()=>this.setState({productId:item.id})}>
```

First things first, you should define your render function on your class, and you should define your onPress function separate from that. For example:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {

  handlePress = (item) => {
    this.decrementCount()
    this.setState({productId: item.id})
  }

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (...code from above, but using this.handlePress rather than your onPress function as currently defined)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I think the real reason that its not working for you right now is that you're trying to call this.setState as a callback in your onPress function. It would probably work as is if you changed your current onPress from:
`onPress={this.decrementCount,()=>this.setState({productId:item.id})}`
to
`onPress={() => this.setState({productId:item.id}, this.decrementCount)}`
as I'm fairly sure you can have a function called as a callback from this.setState.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could probably also just do both state changes in one go:
`this.setState(prevState => ({productId: item.id, count: prevState.count - 1}))`